pytorch built-in method torch.xxx(ops)
Is there any specification about torch.xxx(ops), such as torch.max_pool2d, torch.conv2d? I cannot found it in https://pytorch.org/docs.
How do they differ from their torch.nn.functional.xxx counterpart?
